# How can I get search results from all of children at firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In the database child product 
and this child has several children.
I want to click search and have all children searched, not only one child. 
For example:
The search is by description
or price and not on the name only.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");


FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                .setQuery(reference.orderByChild("pname").startAt(searchinput), Products.class)
                .build();
```

Comment: Can you add your database structure and explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: – Md. Asaduzzaman   I want to search in more than one place orderByChild("pname") i want orderByChild("description") and  orderByChild("price") Do you know what I want to do?

Comment: You can't use more than one `orderByChild` in query of firebase. What you can do is just add one `orderByChild` in your query and implement another one in client side after getting data

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So in your case you could have a property `"pname_description": "value1_value2"` and order/filter on that. For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase